# Delete HTML division by its class name and save the code

Tags: html, regex, parsing, editor

I have a HTML file in the below format :-

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hello"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="goodbye">2</div>
<div class="hello"><p>3</p></div>
<div class="goodbye">4</div>
</div>
```

Please recommend me a program which could remove a particular `div` tag by its class name and save the output file as below :-

```
<div class="container">
<div class="goodbye">2</div>
<div class="goodbye">4</div>
</div>
```

The whole division along with its internal tags should be removed. I have used jQuery, but it does not affect the source code. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**:

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
$('.container .hello').remove();
```

*Side note*: You can use **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** to speed up above selector:

```
$('.container').find('.hello').remove();
```

Comment: It only affects what I see in the browser. The HTML source is never changed. I want the HTML source to change so that I could copy and save the new HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element having class `hello` within `container` and call [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j6Cy6/)**

```
$('.container .hello').remove();
```

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach(), [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: It only affects what I see in the browser. The HTML source is never changed. I want the HTML source to change so that I could copy and save the new HTML code.

Comment: @Adil he wants the element should be removed in html page source it is not possible

Comment: If you want what @sudharsan has told then it is not possible and I cant understand why you want this.

Comment: There are some things inside a scraped data which I do not want. I wan to remove particular divisions from them by their class name from the HTML source code.

Comment: You can not delete from source file through script. although you can put conditions in server side code to generate html in the way you want

Answer (score 0):

So, nobody actually seemed to read what OP asked for. 
Here's an answer for a JavaScript Regular Expression, very dirty and unflexible, but matching your needs.

```
<div class=.(\w*)?.><(.*)</div>
```

Still you may run into problems, because I don't know any editor actually using JavaScript RegEx.

Basically, everything about problems you might run into has been already said in this famous thread: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)